# Sandboxing a function to make it safe?

Tags: javascript, eval, sandbox

I'm trying to sandbox a function in a way to prevent it from doing anything that is considered malicious. Simple example:

```
const fn = (window, setTimeout) => {
    console.log(`window: ${typeof window}`);
    console.log(`setTimeout: ${typeof setTimeout}`);
};

fn (undefined, undefined);

// console output:
// window: undefined
// setTimeout: undefined
```

The function `fn` does not have any access to the `window` or `setTimeout` functions, because they're hidden by the arguments of the same name.

To make this more useful, I'd like to write a higher-order function to do the sandboxing:

```
const sandbox = (fn) => (...args) => {
    return ((window, setTimeout) => {
        return fn.call(args);
    })();
};

const maliciousFn = (a, b) => {
    console.log(`a: ${a}`);
    console.log(`b: ${b}`);
    console.log(`window: ${typeof window}`);
    console.log(`setTimeout: ${typeof setTimeout}`);
    return 42;
};

const safeFn = sandbox(maliciousFn);

console.log (`maliciousFn returns: ${maliciousFn(13, 27)}`);
console.log (`safeFn returns: ${safeFn(13, 27)}`);
```

This doesn't work as the `maliciousFn` has already captured the references of `window`
and `setTimeout`, and the additional wrapper can't change that.

Is it possible to do this properly?

Background: The reason behind this is that I'd like to write a sandboxed `eval` function
that could evaluate any given script safely without the risk of doing anything malicious.
Of course, I'd have to hide all globals, not just `window` and `setTimeout`. But once it
works for `window` and `setTimeout`, I can easily add all the other globals as well.

```
const safeEval = sandbox(eval);
const result = safeEval(someScriptComingFromAnUnsafeSource);
```

Comment: How are you going to defend against DoS attacks like `while(1){}`?

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of that.

Comment: If you really want to sandbox it post it to iframe running on different origin

Comment: This is an interesting way to access the document: `new Text().ownerDocument` which allows you to inject scripts and run arbitrary javascript. All in all, it is (I think) not doable to create a safe eval.